# Send mail through client-side without launching an e-mail client (Silent email)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to send the email for html page. Is there any method to send the email silently i.e without opening the email client.

Can i have some method/way to do this using javascript or jquery ??

In this html page I dont want to show the client that any email is sending.

Any any help????

Comment: Send from the server or on the client's behalf? (Client's behalf is an automatic no)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible. And even if it was, it wouldn't be a cool thing to do.

If you want to send a web page via email why not just ask the user for their email address and then send it yourself server-side? You can use Ajax if you don't want to have a page refresh be required for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. [SquareSend](https://squaresend.com/) is one example. [MailerJs](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3627608) is another. You only embed a tiny javascript in your webpage and you do not need a server.